# Ubuntu and Windows environment

Tags: linux, windows, samba, file-server

Our IT department needs to set up a file server that will hold the organization's documentation and all other important information; it's currently being held on our Windows AD server.

**Main objective: To allow all windows users the ability to access that Linux File server using a networked folder as they did before.**

We decided to use Ubuntu Server 14.04 64-bit. I am no expert in Linux, but I know in the past I have worked on servers using SAMBA; I am not sure if SAMBA is what I need to achieve this.

The Server must be on the Organization's Domain, and be able to be accessed using Active Directory credentials. Is Samba what I need to make this happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Samba is a good choice for your situation. If you've decided to go with Ubuntu, there's a guide [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Samba). This [page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ActiveDirectoryHowto) should set up exactly what you're looking for.

If you're new to Linux, my recommendation is to read that guide for understanding, before attempting any commands. Don't run a command if you're not sure what it will do first.

The command `man man` will explain [man pages](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/man.1.html) and how to use them to find information. Many commands can also be appended with `--help` or `-h` to offer a shorter explanation.

Good luck!